# Will a lexical analyzer recognize two tokens with no whitespace in-between?

Tags: flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I want to simulate a lexical analyzer using Flex.

Part of the program will recognize names of shapes made from five characters, [ABCDE] in all combinations, but only when the number of letters is either one, three or four. In this case it will print the input and the word "shape".

For example if the input is 'A', 'BCD', 'CDBE', it will print 'A: shape'. My question is, given some input like 'AB',with the two characters stuck together,**which is not a valid number of letters if taken as a whole**, what would a real lexical analyzer do? Recognize 'A' as a shape and then 'B' as a shape, or consider it an error?

Comment: That depends entirely on the specification of the language it is analyzing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Flex distinguish between A, AB, and ABC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144755/how-does-flex-distinguish-between-a-ab-and-abc)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the rules are written. If there is a simple rule "[ABCDE]" for all the valid single letters, "AB" will be recognized as two valid tokens "A" and "B". I assume that's not correct, right?

I'm not expert of lexer and parser. Here's just some rough idea.

```
^[ABCDE]{4}$ { /* do sth. */ return TOKEN4; }
^[ABCDE]{3}$ { /* do sth. */ return TOKEN3; }
^[ABCDE]{1}$ { /* do sth. */ return TOKEN1;}
^.*$         { /* report error or throw the input. */ ; }
```